# Eigenvectors of PSL(2,Z) in terms of quadratic integers

Tags: linear-algebra, unimodular-matrices

Suppose I have a matrix A from the modular group, whose eigenvalues are numbers from a suitable quadratic field $Q(\sqrt D)$, where D depends on the trace of the matrix. Is there a way to find the corresponding eigenvectors so their components would be quadratic integers from the same field? Is it possible always, never or just for some subset of the modular group?

Comment: You could just multiply your eigenvectors by some integer to push their components into the ring of quadratic integers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.